# adding two numpy.float64 numbers get wrong result

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to numpy. I tried to add two numpy.float64 numbers, however, the numpy gave me a wrong answer.

Here's my code:(a and b are generated separately by the mean of one numpy array)

```
print(a)
print(type(a))
print(b)
print(type(b))
c = (a + b)/2
print(c)
print(type(c))
```

And here's what I got:

```
1.4617937201411304
<class 'numpy.float64'>
-1.4617937201411302
<class 'numpy.float64'>
1.1102230246251565e-16
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Clearly, the answer should be very close to 0, but what I got is far away from 0.

I guess the problem is that a+b caused an overflow?

However, when I tried to double a, the answer was right:

```
c = (a * 2)/2
```

The answer is:

```
1.4617937201411304
<class 'numpy.float64'>
-1.4617937201411302
<class 'numpy.float64'>
1.4617937201411304
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `e-16` at the end of the print. It means the result is `1.1102230246251565 * 10^(-16)`, which is indeed almost zero.
It's a convention to print numbers with `e` (the exponent) rather then `0.000000....1110`